# How to save image data from clipboard to a file in Python 3 on Debian, using tkinter?

Tags: python, image-processing, tkinter, clipboard, clipboarddata

I'm trying to use the `tkinter` solution for obtaining clipboard image data copied from GIMP, but cannot make it work, saving the data to file:

```
from tkinter import Tk
r = Tk()
r.withdraw()
clip = r.clipboard_get(type="image/png")
r.update()
r.destroy()
with open("testbytes.png", mode="bw+") as f:
    f.write(clip.encode())
```

When I try to open the testbytes.png file, the Image Viewer reports a fatal error, not a PNG file. I obtained the `type` parameter for the `clipboard_get()` call with `r.selection_get(selection='CLIPBOARD', type='TARGETS')`, which returned:

```
'TIMESTAMP TARGETS MULTIPLE SAVE_TARGETS image/png image/bmp image/x-bmp image/x-MS-bmp image/x-icon image/x-ico image/x-win-bitmap image/vnd.microsoft.icon application/ico image/ico image/icon text/ico image/tiff image/jpeg '
```

I think the format of the data on the clipboard is PNG. I've also tried JPEG, BMP and TIFF, but they result in similar errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you looked in the file to see what it looks like, or used some other tool that can attempt to detect the file type? Also, why are you calling `encode` on the data?

Comment: @BryanOakley During the various tests that I was doing, Python reported the type of data on the clipboard being `str`. I use `encode` to get `bytes`. The data looks like this - `b'0x89 0x50 0x4e 0x47 0xd 0xa 0x1a 0xa 0x0 0x0 0x0 0xd 0x49...`. I don't know what other tool to use to get file type.

Comment: I have now run the `file testbytes.png` command in Terminal and get this response: `testbytes.png: ASCII text, with very long lines, with no line terminators`. Not what it should be, is it?

Comment: `b'0x89 0x50 0x4e ...` isn't PNG data, it's a hex dump of PNG data.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks for that! Running `xxd -r -p testbytes.hex > testbytes.png` to convert the hex dump to binary, produces a file that in Image Viewer results in the "PNG file corrupted by ASCII conversion" error. This error results both when I save the original string read from the clipboard, as well as when encoding to bytes. Doing some searches on the topic of hexdump-to-binary conversion, it appears such conversions are not always straightforward. I need to find out what's wrong with the hexdump and a method of converting correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Using a conversion method, obtained in a [separate SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54362179/8803665), for the hexdump of PNG data that `tkinter` provides from the clipboard, the correct code is:

```
from tkinter import Tk
r = Tk()
r.withdraw()
clip = r.clipboard_get(type="image/png")
r.update()
r.destroy()
# Convert hexdump to bytes
clip = bytes([eval(h) for h in clip.strip().split(' ')])
with open("testbytes.png", mode="bw+") as f:
    f.write(clip)
```

Apart from writing out a PNG file, the data may also be loaded with the `pillow` module (formerly known as `PIL`):

```
import io
from PIL import Image
cf = io.BytesIO(clip)
cim = Image.open(cf)
cim.show()
```

As far as I've been able to determine, this is the best method of reading a PNG file from the clipboard into Python 3 on Linux (Debian).

Answer (score 0):

I have **created a tool for this intended for windows**. The code could be used for debian as well. This script monitors for change in your clipboard and pops up a tkinter window asking you the filename to be used for saving the image, if it is not present in the folder. The image is then saved into the folder as a PNG file. It is particularly helpful with the windows shortcut Windows + Shift + S used to snip the screen.

Please find it here: https://github.com/Mitzzzzz/Clipboard-Image-Saver